# How do insert a time window of data into table that partially overlaps with existing rows with unique constraint

Tags: python, mysql

How do insert a time window of data into table that partially overlaps with existing rows with unique constraint.

Here's a code snippet:

```
  # Create the insert strings
column_str = """data_vendor_id, symbol_id, price_date, created_date, 
             last_updated_date, open_price, high_price, low_price, 
             close_price, volume, adj_close_price"""
insert_str = ("%s, " * 11)[:-2]
final_str = "INSERT INTO daily_price (%s) VALUES (%s)" % \
    (column_str, insert_str)
```

When I call this now I get the IntegrityError which makes sense.  Ideally it will let the fresh rows insert and fail gracefully on the redundant rows.  My try/except block unfortunately doesn't permit legit rows and makes the entire query fail:

```
   for i, t in enumerate(tickers):
    print(
        "Adding data for %s: %s out of %s" %
        (t[1], i+1, lentickers)
    )
    yf_data = price_retrieval.get_daily_historic_data_yahoo(t[1], start_date.timetuple())
    try:
        price_retrieval.insert_daily_data_into_db('1', t[0], yf_data)
    except IntegrityError:
        continue
```

Is there a python or mysql solution to making this insertion more fault tolerant?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't permit legit rows"? What keys are on the table, and what do you mean by "partially overlaps"?

Comment: the unique constraint is pricedate and ticker_id.  Partially overlaps means some rows i'm inserting collide with previous rows and some rows are new rows "legit rows".  patricus answer worked.   Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for either `INSERT IGNORE` or `REPLACE`, depending on how you want the duplicate data handled.

**INSERT IGNORE**
If you want to keep the old data and discard the new duplicate data, you want to use `INSERT IGNORE`. This will turn the unique key violations into warnings, and all the non-violating rows will be processed as normal. Without the `IGNORE` keyword, any unique violation will abort the entire `INSERT` batch.

```
final_str = "INSERT IGNORE INTO daily_price (%s) VALUES (%s)" % \
    (column_str, insert_str)
```

[Insert documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html)

**REPLACE**
If you want to overwrite the old data with the new duplicate data, you want to use the `REPLACE` statement instead of `INSERT`. `REPLACE` is a MySQL specific extension to the SQL standard. It will insert non-existing rows, and if it encounters a duplicate row, it will first delete the old row and then insert the new row.

```
final_str = "REPLACE INTO daily_price (%s) VALUES (%s)" % \
    (column_str, insert_str)
```

[Replace documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replace.html)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding it that `price_retrieval.insert_daily_data_into_db` is inserting many rows, but is interrupting on the first failed row? You would need to wrap the individual record insertion with a `try` rather than wrapping the group of them.